# Customizing JTable.print() method to print table data with varying row heights

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

**GOAL**:  Print a table with each row having varying row heights to GUI  and  to a physical printer using custom renderers.

I am able to print the JTable data to a table within my Java Swing GUI by extending the `TableCellRenderer` using a customized renderer to change the row height for each row depending on the height needed for each row.

```
int height = stringValue.length * 22;
if(height > table.getRowHeight(row)) {
    table.setRowHeight(row, height);
}
```

This works for the GUI display and outputs perfectly to my screen.

However, when I want to physically print a paper copy of  the entire table, I am unable to correctly print the new row heights using the `jtable.print()` method.  Instead, the data is being cut off because only a single row height is used for all rows.  i.e. it ignores my new inputs (from the looks of it).

Comment: Wouldn't a dedicated report-generating library be better for paper output? Something like JasperReports comes to mind (although I'm not sure if it is still a viable actively supported product).

Comment: Yep, it still is being supported with its last release a few months ago. Site: [JasperReports® Library](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library). Plus it is free to use, distributed under a GNU AGPLv3 license.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Would I be able to add JasperReports to my project without really changing my renderers or my Table settings?  

I mean, its just a library right?

Comment: You wouldn't change any of the screen renderers, but if you used this (or other reporting libraries) you wouldn't use screen renderers to generate paper reports. For those you'd send the non-GUI model data to your code that interfaces with the report-gen library, and then use the Report-gen library settings to help render the data to paper.

Comment: Okay, i just watched a 2 minute youtube video demoing how it works.  This looks very doable.  

Thank you for your time.  I was not aware of the existence of JasperReports.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but I've seen it mentioned often enough, and given its licensing, you've nothing to lose in trying it.

Comment: *using a customized renderer to change the row height* - the renderer should NOT be used to change the row height. The job of a renderer is to display the data, not change properties of the table. Your code to set the height should be done after loading data into the model. Check out the [Table Column Adjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) which contains a block of code to demonstrate how to manually invoke the renderer externally so you can set the row height.

Comment: @camickr  Okay, but why is changing the value within the renderer cause issues?  Thanks